# Inaccurate calculation of vertex positions in the projection

Tags: three.js, zbuffer

There is a sphere of radius 7000 that is wrapped in Object3D with the position (0,0,0)
When the zoom camera as close as possible to the heights (eg 0.2 from vertices), we get the following:

[image]
That is, the larger the value of the vertices, the worse the approximation accuracy in the camera thereto. And if the node is in the center Object3D, then there is no such problem. How to fix it?

Changing near and far does not give any result, works only if remove Object3D and set the vertices of the geometry closer to the center of the scene

Comment: Don't you work with integer coordinates at places ?

Comment: Can you edit [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95t964o0/) and provide a live example?

Comment: I have an example http://jsfiddle.net/eho5g2go/2/ it is necessary that coordinates of the vertices of the mesh was large value relative to the center of the scene, but because of this error are obtained in the calculation, although it is not dependent on the far and near

Comment: @WestLangley, this example http://jsfiddle.net/eho5g2go/4/ is more similar to my problem. there is a very small part of a sphere whose radius is equal to 6700. The camera is located at a distance of about 0.05 of each vertex. Due to the large values of the coordinates of vertices and a very small value of the distance camera to the vertices I get with such a problem. I do not know how to solve it

Comment: 1. Your fiddle is using a version of three.js that is 2 years old. Please use the fiddle I wrote for you as a template. 2. One solution: http://jsfiddle.net/eho5g2go/5/

Comment: But if I have dozens of these meshes,then it is necessary to do for each geometry translation when moving the camera. This is a rather expensive way ... hmm .... probably no other way?

Comment: Сhanging coordinates of the vertices of each mesh did not affect significantly the performance. I think this will be the final solution to the problem, although it complicates the structure. Thank U.